# Convert bevel node output to black/white

Tags: edges, bevel

I want to use the new bevel node to simulate chipped paint along edges. I find the edges by using the cross product of the normal outputs of bevel and geometry nodes. However, the output is blurred around the edges and I need a sharp transition to achieve the desired effect, so I am trying to use a color ramp with both positions set to 0.5 to convert the greyscale map to black/white. But it doesn't work, the output is still a greyscale gradient.
How can I fix this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the *Pointiness* output from *Geometry* node, it does what you want and you don't need a special build of Blender.

Comment: I don't want to use pointiness because I am working with low poly models. For pointiness to work, I'd need to refine the mesh significantly.

Comment: You can use Subsurf set to Simple to get nice results on low-poly, but I agree it's not ideal. I am afraid you will have to use an OSL shader or wait till Bevel node behaves more nicely..

Comment: Unfortunately, "In the latest 2.79 daily build, is it possible to convert the Bevel node's RGB normal maps to BW edge highlighters?" does not answer my question. As I mentioned in the original post, I know how to use bevel to find the edges, but the output is always blurred and I can't convert it to 2-color black & white. This is necessary to simulate an actual "chipped paint" effect, not merely "worn edges".

Comment: I am voting to reopen the question, because it is not a duplicate. The problem is in the way the Bevel node sampling works, not in how to get BW edges. I am skeptical there is a nice solution now, but imho the question should stay open, maybe there will be solution someday or someone cleverly finds a good workaround.

Comment: Tried this in Blender 2.80 and it is still the same issue. I can't convert the greyscale output to sharp black & white. Did anyone find a solution in the meantime?